# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'object.GetType()'

Tags: c#

I´m getting this kind of error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'object.GetType()'

```
XmlSerializer rd = new XmlSerializer(Roll.GetType())
```

class:

```
  public class Roll
{
    public int Code = 0;
    public string Name = "";
    public DateTime Date = DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

If you need anymore info let me know.

Thank you

Comment: We don't have the necessary code to reproduce this error.

Comment: @Seb tell me what you need, the code from the button that I want to run?

Comment: It's not about what I need. You're the one who wants help. You need to create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make the title more descriptive of an actual problem. *What's going wrong here?* has zero meaningful information. Question titles should actually describe the problem you're experiencing or the question you're asking in a way that will be useful to a future reader who finds it in a search result. You've also provided no context for the single line of code. If you want our help. **be specific** about the problem, **include the relevant information**, and ask a **specific question**.

Comment: Public fields are against best practices, you should use properties.

Comment: @ErikPhilips thats how I needed to be can´t change it

Comment: Why are you down-voting a post from somebody requiring help in a field which is knowledge is basic?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Although I agree with you, SO is not a *find the answer* website.  It's a *question and answer* website, thus a well thought out question describing what someone is trying to do, what is happening and what is expected, helps future users instead of just the *original poster*.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Point taken. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Practically, it means you should be using `typeof(Roll)` instead of `Roll.GetType()`.  I.e.,

```
XmlSerializer rd = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Roll));
```

Techincally, it means that `Roll` is a class, and `GetType()` is a valid instance method of that class (by inheritance) but it is not a valid static method. Therefore you can call `myRoll.GetType()` if `myRoll` is an object instance of type `Roll`, but you can't call `Roll.GetType()`.

Answer (score 1):

It means that in order to invoke (i.e call) the `GetType()` method on `Roll`, you need an object instance that is of type `Roll` class, since `GetType()` method is not a static method.

So like others have said, use `typeof` as follows.

```
XmlSerializer rd = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Roll));
```

Are you trying to serialize `Roll` instances into a file or something
? If yes, try example below.

Ex:

```
private void SerializeRoll(string filename)
{
    XmlSerializer rd = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Roll));

    // Instantiate Roll, fill it with data.
    Roll oneRoll = new Roll();
    oneRoll.Code = 1;
    oneRoll.Name = "Test Code"; 

    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
    ser.Serialize(writer, oneRoll );
    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: @Shiva should I put this in the class I created where I defined the type of inputs should be made or in the Code are that defines what each button does?

Comment: @Phyti Please update your question to add the code that defines the `Roll` class.  Make sure to remove sensitive info (ex: passwords or other proprietary stuff).

Comment: @Seb this isn't a guess. This is the answer.

Comment: @MillieSmith What if `Roll` is not a type that can be instantiated, for example an interface or an abstract class? Is this the answer, then? My problem is that this answer relies upon incomplete information that hasn't been provided. The other answers still rely upon guesswork, but are at least more comprehensive and likely to cover all possibilities.

Comment: @Seb My original answer was complete because OP asked what an error meant, and I explained it to him. After I asked OP to update his question with `Roll` class definition, he did that, and now this updated answer is also complete. Take a deep breath bro.

Comment: @Seb the answer remains the same. An instance is required.

Comment: @Shiva I'm just trying to help you form better answers. You don't have to accept my help, if you don't want to. If you do want to accept my help, then my suggestion is to try to avoid guesswork (e.g. you didn't initially have enough information to suggest that `new Roll()` was valid; that was a guess). It's just advice... Take it or leave it.

Comment: @MillieSmith If you were trying to argue that this answer relied upon no guess-work, then you just implied that you were wrong... and no, `new Roll()` wouldn't have been correct if the type `Roll` were an `interface` or an `abstract class`. Anyway, I've said all I need, and given an opportunity for improvement should Shiva so desire, so this is my cue to depart from this conversation. Peace :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass the `Type` object for the `Roll` class to the `XmlSerializer` constructor, but you're using the `GetType()` function, which is an instance method rather than a static method. Instance methods need to be called from an object, as opposed to a static method, which can be called from the class itself.

In order to do what you want, without an object of the `Roll` type, use

```
XmlSerializer rd = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Roll));
```

The `typeof` operator returns a `Type` object describing the class passed as its parameter.